# How can i rotate arrow when you hover on select element

Tags: html, css, select, element, image-rotation

This is how it look like

[image]

And i want to rotate this arrow when you hover select element
I tried: `select:hover ~ .arrow {transform: rotate(270deg);}` but it doesnt work
I also tried do it withour '~' but the same.
and when i place it (image) to select element it doesnt even show image
maybe i have to put this image without div

```css
.vip-section .options select {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: .5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.vip-section .options .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 370px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
}

.vip-section .options select:hover~.arrow {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="vip-section">
  <div class="text-options">
    <h2>V.I.P Announcement</h2>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="arrow">
        <img src="/Images/arrow-down-sign-to-navigate (1).png" alt="">
      </div>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." name="" id="">
      <select>
        <option value="">Select price</option>
        <option value="">500$ - 1.500$</option>
        <option value="">1.500$ - 2.500$</option>
        <option value="">2.500$ - 5.000$</option>
        <option value="">5.000$ - 10.000$</option>
        <option value="">10.000$ - 20.000$</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option value="">Select brand</option>
        <option value="">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="">BMW</option>
        <option value="">Audi</option>
        <option value="">Ferrari</option>
        <option value="">Chevrolet</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to replace your last line with the following: `.vip-section .options:hover .arrow {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}` It should work. Your selector `~` is not suitable for such case.

Comment: it working but when i hover other elements which in options div this arrow also rotating

Comment: problem is all other elements are in the div options, all at same level : arrow, input and the 2 selects. Either you define the hover only on the arrow, .vip-section .options .arrow:hover { transform: rotate(270deg);}, rotate only when cursor is on the arrow. Or you'll have to structure your HTML differently